# Error with replacing "_" with letter in hangman using .replace() using python

Tags: python

I hope you are all doing well!

I am a relative beginner in Python and I am trying to program a hangman game but I seem to be getting some errors while attempting to replace the "_" with the letter that the user guessed correctly. I tried a lot of testing and printing at different places but I still can't figure out where the error is. Can someone please help me? Here is my code:

```
#import random
import secrets

with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

def randomWord():
    wordR = secrets.choice(lines)
    wordR = wordR.lower()
    return wordR

def hangMan(word):
    guessWord = "_" *len(word)
    correctGuesses = []
    wrongGuesses = []
    lives = 0
    guessedWord = False
    print(word)
    print(
                """
                    O
                   O O
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
    )
    while not guessedWord and lives < 7:
        print(guessWord + "\n")
        print("Correct Guesses: ", ",".join(correctGuesses)+"\n")
        print("Wrong Guesses: ", ",".join(wrongGuesses)+"\n")
        guessLetter = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if guessLetter.isalpha:
            if guessLetter in word:
                print( f"Nice job! You guessed the letter: {guessLetter}"+"\n")
                correctGuesses.append(guessLetter)
                print(f"You have {7-lives} lives left!\n")
                #replace the _ with the letter
                for x, i in enumerate(word):
                    if guessLetter == i:
                        guessWord = guessWord.replace(guessWord[x], guessLetter) #not working need fix
                if guessWord == word:
                    guessedWord = True
                    print(f"Nice job! You have successfully guessed the word: {word}")
                    break
            elif guessLetter in correctGuesses:
                print("You have already guessed this letter correctly before!\n ")
            elif not guessLetter in word:
                print(f"{guessLetter} isn't one of the characters!\n ")
                wrongGuesses.append(guessLetter)
                lives+=1
        print(guessWord + "\n")
        if lives == 0:
            print(
                """
                    O
                   O O
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 1:
            print (
                """
                   O O
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 2:
            print(
                """
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 3:
            print(
                """
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 4:
            print(
                """
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 5:
            print (
                """
              O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 6:
            print(f"Oh no! The pyramid got completely deconstructed! You lost! The word was {word}!")

def main():
    wordR2 = randomWord()
    hangMan(wordR2)
    while "yes" in input("Do you want to play again? ").lower():
        wordR2 = randomWord()
        hangMan(wordR2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: _but I seem to be getting some errors_ Tell us what those errors are.  Saying "I got errors" isn't really very helpful.

Comment: Is it an error, or is the code just not working as intended? If it is an error, then please post what the error says.

Comment: `replace()` replaces _all_ the occurrences of the old string.  `guessWord` starts out as all underscores, so if you replace one of them, it replaces _all_ of them.

Comment: Also, the `elif guessLetter in correctGuesses:` will never be run.`if guessLetter in word:` will be true if the letter was already guessed correctly. I recommend switching the two if statements.

Answer (score 0):

So since when I run it, I don't get any errors, I'm assuming that you mean it just doesn't work as intended.

First, in your original code, `guessLetter in correctGuesses` was after `guessLetter in word`, so `guessLetter in correctGuesses` would always be skipped. Flipping the order fixes that.

Second, using `guessWord.replace(guessWord[x], guessLetter)` causes all occurrences of `guessWord[x]` to be replaced with `guessLetter`. So if you have `guessWord = "_____"` with `word = "hello"`, and you guess `"e"`, then if you do `guessWord = guessWord.replace("_", "e")`, *all* "_"s would be replaced, causing `guessWord == "eeeee"`. You need to change the specific index, but since strings are immutable, you can't do `guessWord[1] = "e"`, you have to add together three strings: the first string is the unchanged first part, the second part is the changed letter, and the third part is the unchanged last part (`"guessWord = guessWord[:1]+"e"+guessWord[2:]`).

Third, the most minor part, is that if you lose 6 lives(`lives==6`), it says you lose, but you can continue. Just add a `break` to end the current game.

```
#import random
import secrets

with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

def randomWord():
    wordR = secrets.choice(lines)
    wordR = wordR.lower()
    return wordR

def hangMan(word):
    guessWord = "_" *len(word)
    correctGuesses = []
    wrongGuesses = []
    lives = 0
    guessedWord = False
    print(word)
    print(
                """
                    O
                   O O
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
    )
    while not guessedWord and lives < 7:
        print(guessWord + "\n")
        print("Correct Guesses: ", ",".join(correctGuesses)+"\n")
        print("Wrong Guesses: ", ",".join(wrongGuesses)+"\n")
        guessLetter = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if guessLetter.isalpha:
            if guessLetter in correctGuesses: #needs to be in front, otherwise it will never run
                print("You have already guessed this letter correctly before!\n ")
            elif guessLetter in word:
                print( f"Nice job! You guessed the letter: {guessLetter}"+"\n")
                correctGuesses.append(guessLetter)
                print(f"You have {7-lives} lives left!\n")
                for x, i in enumerate(word):
                    if guessLetter == i:
                        guessWord = guessWord[:x]+guessLetter+guessWord[x+1:]
                        #can't use replace, because that replaces all of it
                        #I used indexing to add three strings together: the beginning part of the word, the letter, and the end part
                if guessWord == word:
                    guessedWord = True
                    print(f"Nice job! You have successfully guessed the word: {word}")
                    break

            elif not guessLetter in word:
                print(f"{guessLetter} isn't one of the characters!\n ")
                wrongGuesses.append(guessLetter)
                lives+=1
        print(guessWord + "\n")
        if lives == 0:
            print(
                """
                    O
                   O O
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 1:
            print (
                """
                   O O
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 2:
            print(
                """
                  O O O
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 3:
            print(
                """
                 O O O O
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 4:
            print(
                """
                O O O O O
               O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 5:
            print (
                """
              O O O O O O
                """
            )
        elif lives == 6:
            print(f"Oh no! The pyramid got completely deconstructed! You lost! The word was {word}!")
            break # so that game ends when you lose

def main():
    wordR2 = randomWord()
    hangMan(wordR2)
    while "yes" in input("Do you want to play again? ").lower():
        wordR2 = randomWord()
        hangMan(wordR2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response but you are a legend! Thank you so much <3!

Answer (score -2):

str.replace() is an inplace method, which means what you just coded would return a NoneType.

So, maybe remove `guessWord =`  will work.

Comment: _str.replace() is an inplace method_ no it is not.